force the header onto every "list of figures" and "list of tables" page
I am using this code to add headers ('Table' and 'Page') to every page in the list of tables, which spans 9 pages. However, this creates two additional empty pages that I have tried to delete:
%   
\newif\ifendLOT
\newcommand*{\lotheader}{
\ifendLOT\else\hbox to \linewidth%
  {\noindent{Table}~\hfill{Page}}\par%
  \vspace{12pt}%
  \afterpage{\lotheader}
\fi}%

I would like to add the headers 'Table' and 'Page' to the 9 pages in the list of tables. As an example:  

Welcome! Can you provide code for a small document we can use to reproduce the current situation? As it stands, your question can't really be answered except by guessing what you're doing. This kind of thing depends on your class, relevant packages and associated configuration.

A lot depends on the document class.  You should be able to achieve the desired effect with \pagestyle and \markboth, although you will need to edit \listoffigures and \listoftables (all the work is done by \@starttoc)
